# How to adjust height of links with CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, footer

I'm using some Fontface vector icon links in a footer and am unable to adjust the height for "footer a" which the links are contained in. I've put a red border around them just to highlight the problem. Ideally, the when tabbing through the links, the border would simply be the height and width of the icons.

I wrapped the "footer a" in it's own div("#footer-links") but "footer a" seems to ignore this and the height extends beyond both #footer-links and the footer itself.

I've tried adjusting a few different qualities of the "footer a" but am having no luck. Any suggestions?

Below is the HTML and CSS:

```css
/* CSS for all pages */

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}


/*HEADER/NAVBAR*/

img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 300px;
}

header {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  display: inline-flexbox;
  border-bottom: black solid 2px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
}

nav li {
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}

nav li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.1rem;
  height: 10px;
}

.border {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#games-ul {
  background: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47px;
}

#games-li li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  height: 30px;
}

#games-li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}


/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#footer-wrap {
  height: 60px;
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#footer-copy {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}

#footer-links {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

footer a {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 46px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}


/* INDEX ONLY */

#testimonial {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 18%;
  width: 1000px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

#quote {
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: fit-content;
  color: green;
  display: block;
}

#author {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}

#grids {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(160px, 1fr) repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 250px);
  gap: 4rem;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

#grid1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

#grid2 {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

article {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.button-link {
  padding: 0.7em 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgb(194, 192, 192);
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/*ABOUT*/

#about-div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
}


/* form styling */

.form-div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 430px;
}

#login-div {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#register-div {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#contact-div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 430px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input {
  font-size: large;
  width: 430px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  padding: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgb(194, 192, 192);
  width: fit-content;
}

input[type='submit']:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type='submit']:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type='submit']:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input:focus:not([type=submit]) {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

label[for='terms'] {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#checkbox-div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: auto;
}

#register-div {
  /*Hides Registration Div*/
  display: none;
}

#contactMessage {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contactMessage:focus {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <h1><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="border" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li id="games-li"><a class="border" href="#">Games</a>
        <ul id="games-ul">
          <li><a href="games/anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt </a></li>
          <li><a href="games/math-facts.html">Math Facts Practice</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="border" href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Login </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="testimonial"></div>
  <div id="quote"></div>
  <div id="author"></div>
  <section id="grids">
    <div id="grid1">
      <h3 class="article-title">Anagram Hunt</h3>
      <article id="article1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus. Praesent vel rutrum lectus. Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. Sed eu luctus
        sem.
      </article>
      <a class="button-link" href="games/anagram-hunt.html" title="Play Anagram Hunt">Play</a>
    </div>
    <div id="grid2">
      <h3 class="article-title">Math Facts Practice</h3>
      <article id="article2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus. Praesent vel rutrum lectus. Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. Sed eu luctus
        sem.
      </article>
      <a class="button-link" href="games/math-facts.html" title="Play Math Facts Practice">Play</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <div id="footer-wrap">
    <div id="footer-copy">

      &#169 2021 Play2Learn
    </div>
    <div id="footer-links">


      <a href="contact-us.html" title="Contact Us"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></a>
      <a href="https://instagram.com" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
      <a href="https://facebook.com" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: The next time you include your code please use a code snippet (**Ctrl+M**). A code snippet can be run and show the output directly.

Answer (score 0):

notice the changes in css of the following elements:

footer

#footer-wrap

#footer-links

footer a

.fab, .fas

```css
/* CSS for all pages */

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}


/*HEADER/NAVBAR*/

img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 300px;
}

header {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  display: inline-flexbox;
  border-bottom: black solid 2px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
}

nav li {
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}

nav li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.1rem;
  height: 10px;
}

.border {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#games-ul {
  background: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47px;
}

#games-li li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  height: 30px;
}

#games-li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}


/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#footer-wrap {
  
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#footer-copy {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}

#footer-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

footer a {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 36px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fas, .fab{
padding: 0px !important;
margin: 0px;
height: auto;
}


/* INDEX ONLY */

#testimonial {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 18%;
  width: 1000px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

#quote {
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: fit-content;
  color: green;
  display: block;
}

#author {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}

#grids {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(160px, 1fr) repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 250px);
  gap: 4rem;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

#grid1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

#grid2 {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

article {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.button-link {
  padding: 0.7em 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgb(194, 192, 192);
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/*ABOUT*/

#about-div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
}


/* form styling */

.form-div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 430px;
}

#login-div {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#register-div {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#contact-div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-div h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 430px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input {
  font-size: large;
  width: 430px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  padding: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgb(194, 192, 192);
  width: fit-content;
}

input[type='submit']:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type='submit']:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type='submit']:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input:focus:not([type=submit]) {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

label[for='terms'] {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#checkbox-div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: auto;
}

#register-div {
  /*Hides Registration Div*/
  display: none;
}

#contactMessage {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contactMessage:focus {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <h1><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="border" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li id="games-li"><a class="border" href="#">Games</a>
        <ul id="games-ul">
          <li><a href="games/anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt </a></li>
          <li><a href="games/math-facts.html">Math Facts Practice</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="border" href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Login </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="testimonial"></div>
  <div id="quote"></div>
  <div id="author"></div>
  <section id="grids">
    <div id="grid1">
      <h3 class="article-title">Anagram Hunt</h3>
      <article id="article1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus. Praesent vel rutrum lectus. Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. Sed eu luctus
        sem.
      </article>
      <a class="button-link" href="games/anagram-hunt.html" title="Play Anagram Hunt">Play</a>
    </div>
    <div id="grid2">
      <h3 class="article-title">Math Facts Practice</h3>
      <article id="article2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cura bitur tristique odio ac sem congue luctus. Praesent vel rutrum lectus. Nam mattis finibus odio. Suspendisse ligula orci, ullamcorper vitae nulla nec, tempor auctor felis. Sed eu luctus
        sem.
      </article>
      <a class="button-link" href="games/math-facts.html" title="Play Math Facts Practice">Play</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <div id="footer-wrap">
    <div id="footer-copy">

      &#169 2021 Play2Learn
    </div>
    <div id="footer-links">


      <a href="contact-us.html" title="Contact Us"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></a>
      <a href="https://instagram.com" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
      <a href="https://facebook.com" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

EXP:
Footer:
removed fixed height. so that the footer wrap area get the height of its contents.

#footer-wrap:
display changed to flex from inline. so that the child elements height can be manipulated.

footer a
display changed to inline-block to flex and flex-flow : row makes the contents to align to its parent (which is also a flex),

text-decoration: none ==>> font awesome is a font and a by default has underline, so made it none.

.fab .fas ==>> removed padding/margin if font awesome has default padding.

further reference: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Comment: This worked really well. I appreciate your time.